# Sort array desc and asc Python

Tags: python

```
{
0: ['70', '70', '70', 'A12345678', 'JONE', 'BIT', 70, 'C'],
1: ['80', '80', '80', 'A12334567', 'ERIC', 'DIT', 80, 'CP'],
2: ['55', '60', '70', 'A12345679', 'HARRY', 'BIT', 63, 'P'],
3: ['45', '45', '45', 'A11223344', 'NEW', 'BIT', 45, 'F']
}
```

I have an array like this in python I need to sort it on bases of index 6 70,80,63,45 values in array. I try to print it but I am unable to sort this type of array .

Comment: That's not an array, that's a dictionary.  It would be easy to convert it to a list, at which time the normal list `sorted` function could be used with a custom sort key.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above, I pull the values into a list of its own, then sort the list.

```
data = {
0: ['70', '70', '70', 'A12345678', 'JONE', 'BIT', 70, 'C'],
1: ['80', '80', '80', 'A12334567', 'ERIC', 'DIT', 80, 'CP'],
2: ['55', '60', '70', 'A12345679', 'HARRY', 'BIT', 63, 'P'],
3: ['45', '45', '45', 'A11223344', 'NEW', 'BIT', 45, 'F']
}

from pprint import pprint
items = list(data.values())
print("Unsorted")
pprint(items)
items.sort( key=lambda l : l[6] )
print("Sorted")
pprint(items)
```

Output:

```
Unsorted
[['70', '70', '70', 'A12345678', 'JONE', 'BIT', 70, 'C'],
 ['80', '80', '80', 'A12334567', 'ERIC', 'DIT', 80, 'CP'],
 ['55', '60', '70', 'A12345679', 'HARRY', 'BIT', 63, 'P'],
 ['45', '45', '45', 'A11223344', 'NEW', 'BIT', 45, 'F']]
Sorted
[['45', '45', '45', 'A11223344', 'NEW', 'BIT', 45, 'F'],
 ['55', '60', '70', 'A12345679', 'HARRY', 'BIT', 63, 'P'],
 ['70', '70', '70', 'A12345678', 'JONE', 'BIT', 70, 'C'],
 ['80', '80', '80', 'A12334567', 'ERIC', 'DIT', 80, 'CP']]
```